# Possible bug with setHint

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a tabhost with one class. When I change some xml's components in code (like a background botton, lists, even the text of the editext) this works perfectly. But when I try to change the hint of edittext, it doesn't change.

```
switch (currentScreen) {
    case Constants.SHOPS:
         edit_text.setText(R.string.search_shops); // It works
         fillListShops();
         adaptador = new AdaptadorListas<T>(this, list);
         break;
    case Constants.ROUTES:
         edit_text.setHint(R.string.search_shops); // It doesn't work
         fillListRoutes();
         adaptador = new AdaptadorListas<T>(this, lista);
         break;
```

}

Comment: can you post what value you have declared for this `R.string.search_shops` in strings.xml ?

Comment: Sure. <string name="search_shops">Buscar establecimiento</string>

Comment: in your routes Adapter are you trying to use lista or is this a spelling mistake and should in fact be list? Also, do you get any error message, if so please post the logs.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is a spelling mistake. It would be 'list'. But in code is ok. No, there is no error in log, also there isn't any eror when debugging.So... I don't know.